# Subqueryload does not work when using slice

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have written a code in python using sqlalchemy fetching data from MySQL. When the page is 1 (start is 0 and end is 10), everything works fine but when the page is 2 (start is 10 and end is 20), the db_salon and db_user_paymant is null.

I tried using join and joinedload but still it does not work.

```
def get_user_bookings(db: Session, user_id: int, page: int):
    start = (page - 1) * 10
    end = (page * 10)
    db_user_bookings = db.query(DbBasketMain).options(
        subqueryload("db_basket_services"), subqueryload("db_salon"),
        subqueryload("db_user_payment")).filter(
            DbBasketMain.user_id == user_id, DbBasketMain.salon_id != None).slice(
                start, end).all()
    for each_booking in db_user_bookings:
        each_booking.salon_name = each_booking.db_salon.name
        for each_service in each_booking.db_basket_services:
            if (each_service.barber_id):
                db_barber = get_barber_by_id(
                    db=db, barber_id=each_service.barber_id)
                each_service.barber_name = db_barber.name + " " + db_barber.family
                each_service.barber_image = get_barber_profile_image(
                    db=db, barber_id=each_service.barber_id)
    return db_user_bookings
```

Comment: As I said, when the page is 1, everything works fine, so I didn't post the data structure and other details.

Comment: No one? any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using slice, It is a must to use `order_by`.

Changing to `order_by(DbBasketMain.id).slice(start, end)` solved the problem.